# Find norm of operator $L(x,y)=(x+3y,y-x)$

Tags: calculus, normed-spaces

I'm trying to tackle the following question, but with no success...

> Let $L: \ \mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R^2}$ be an operator such that $L(x,y)=(x+3y,y-x)$.
>
> Find $\|L\|$.

So, I know that I need to find $\displaystyle \sup\left(\frac{\|Lx\|}{\|x\|}\right)$. I have calculated the norms and found the gradient. I got that the sup is $1+\sqrt{5}$, but I'm not sure it's correct and I'm pretty sure there's a lot easier way.

Please don't use Lagrange multipliers because we haven't covered this topic yet.

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify what topics you have covered? Lagrange multipliers are typically covered in a freshman calculus class, but operator norms are usually upper-division...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same answer as @Galc27

We have
$$
\|L(x,y)\| = \sqrt{(x+3y)^2+(y-x)^2} =  \sqrt2\sqrt{x^2+2xy+5y^2}. \tag 1
$$
Now, $\|(x,y)\|=1$ implies $x^2+y^2=1$, so $(1)$ simplifies to
$$\sqrt{1+2xy+4y^2}. $$
Substituting $x = \sqrt{1-y^2}$ yields
$$\sqrt2\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1-y^2}y+4y^2}. $$
When $y=\sqrt{\frac12+\frac1{\sqrt5}}$, we have
$$\left\|L\left(1 - \sqrt{\frac12+\frac1{\sqrt5}}, \sqrt{\frac12+\frac1{\sqrt5}} \right)\right\|=1+\sqrt 5. $$

Comment: Why can we assume that $||(x,y)||=1$?

Comment: That's the definition of operator norm: $\|T\|=\sup_{\|f\|=1}\|Tf\|$.

Comment: With the $y$ missing in $2\sqrt{1-y^2}$ the answer is different.

Comment: This question got me really exhausted. But I did get what you got. 
Just didn't use hessian, but elementary calculus operation.

Comment: I used Wolfram. 10 years after I took calc I, I don't always feel the need to differentiate nasty functions by hand.

Comment: @Math1000, THank you for your answer and for the correction. It's satisfying to know that my answer was correct.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix of   $ L $ with respect to standard basis is 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1\\
3 &  1\\
\end{bmatrix}.
Hence $L^*L$ is 
\begin{bmatrix}
10 &2\\
2 &2
\end{bmatrix}

The eigen values of the above matrix are $6+\sqrt 5,6-\sqrt 5$

Hence the required norm is $(6+\sqrt5 )^{1/2}=1+\sqrt5$

Comment: please let me know if you want detailed arguments

Comment: Thank you for an helpful answer! (+1)

Comment: you are wellcome...

Answer (score 1):

For linear operators the norm reduces to being the eigenvalue with the largest modulus. Given L can be written as a 2x2 matrix acting on (x, y) you shouldn't have any problems using such an approach.

Comment: More of a comment than an answer